# Why Composer fails to install laraveldaily/quickadmin

Tags: php, laravel-5.3, yaf-php-framework

Why `Composer` fails to install `laraveldaily/quickadmin` 
`composer require laraveldaily/quickadmin`

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

```
 Problem 1
    - laraveldaily/quickadmin 2.0.0 requires yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle ^6.18 -> satisfiable by yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle[v6.18.0, v6.18.1, v6.18.2, v6.19.0, v6.20.0, v6.21.0, v6.21.1].
    - laraveldaily/quickadmin 2.0.1 requires yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle ^6.18 -> satisfiable by yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle[v6.18.0, v6.18.1, v6.18.2, v6.19.0, v6.20.0, v6.21.0, v6.21.1].
    - laraveldaily/quickadmin 2.0.2 requires yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle ^6.18 -> satisfiable by yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle[v6.18.0, v6.18.1, v6.18.2, v6.19.0, v6.20.0, v6.21.0, v6.21.1].
    - yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle v6.18.0 requires dompdf/dompdf ^0.7 -> satisfiable by dompdf/dompdf[v0.7.0].
    - yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle v6.18.1 requires dompdf/dompdf ^0.7 -> satisfiable by dompdf/dompdf[v0.7.0].
    - yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle v6.18.2 requires dompdf/dompdf ^0.7 -> satisfiable by dompdf/dompdf[v0.7.0].
    - yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle v6.19.0 requires dompdf/dompdf ^0.7 -> satisfiable by dompdf/dompdf[v0.7.0].
    - yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle v6.20.0 requires dompdf/dompdf ^0.7 -> satisfiable by dompdf/dompdf[v0.7.0].
    - yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle v6.21.0 requires dompdf/dompdf ^0.7 -> satisfiable by dompdf/dompdf[v0.7.0].
    - yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle v6.21.1 requires dompdf/dompdf ^0.7 -> satisfiable by dompdf/dompdf[v0.7.0].
    - dompdf/dompdf v0.7.0 requires ext-gd * -> the requested PHP extension gd is missing from your system.
    - Installation request for laraveldaily/quickadmin ^2.0 -> satisfiable by laraveldaily/quickadmin[2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2].

  To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in those .ini files:
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/15-xml.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-curl.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-dom.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mbstring.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-simplexml.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-wddx.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xmlreader.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xmlwriter.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-xsl.ini
  You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.

Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Comment: "**the requested PHP extension gd is missing from your system**" - you need to install it.

Comment: It may not be enabled for php-cli, you can enable like this;

sudo phpenmod gd

UPDATE

I guess, you are using ppa:ondrej php package (5.6), which is confusing you with default ubuntu 14.04 php package (5.5.9).

To install php 5.6 gd library from ppa:ondrej, you should use:

sudo apt-get install php5.6-gd

Answer (score 0):

Check in composer version of the yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle and update it to suitable ^6.18, read [composer versions syntax](https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/versions.md#caret)

```
Problem 1 - laraveldaily/quickadmin 2.0.0 requires yajra/laravel-datatables-oracle ^6.18
```

You have check of those extensions are enabled in php.ini In console type `php --ini`

```
Problem 2 To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled
```